# Can git store or control directory user, group or permissions

Tags: linux, git, permissions, file-permissions

I have developed a few `git` repositories for a web application.  As part of the deployment process, a few of the folders need to be writable by Apache for file uploads.  Does git have any control over this for either the user or group, or the respective permissions?

Comment: Do you want to prevent Apache from writing? Because git won't stop Apache from doing anything to the repo

Comment: Ideally: `rwxrwxr-x` for the folder with user = default user and group = apache.  That way file upload functionality works out of the box.  I am just wondering if git manages owners.

Comment: Git won't prevent the owners permissions because the respective OS in your case Linux already does that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

git can only set this for the entire repository, not for a subdirectory. Run in the root of your repo:

```
sudo chgrp -R apache .
sudo chmod -R ug+rwX *
git config core.sharedRepository group
```